# systemd timer stuck running at the first attempt to trigger its associated oneshot service

Tags: systemd

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how "oneshot" services are handled by associated timers. Here's a dummy unit and a timer supposed to trigger it every 5' (on `systemd-247.3-7+deb11u1`):

```
# systemctl cat dummy.timer dummy.service 
# /etc/systemd/system/dummy.timer
[Unit]
Description=Trigger dummy service every 5'

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*:0/5
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target

# /etc/systemd/system/dummy.service
[Unit]
Description=dummy one-shot service for timer testing

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=echo "Dummy start"
ExecStop=echo "Dummy stop"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The dummy service is not a daemon but it is supposed to change the system's state, hence
the reason for `RemainAfterExit` and for `ExecStop` to rollback the effects of repeated system updates made by `ExecStart`.

At first, everything looks fine:

```
# systemctl start dummy.timer dummy.service
... 
# systemctl status dummy.timer dummy.service 
● dummy.timer - Trigger dummy service every 5'
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dummy.timer; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (waiting) since Fri 2023-04-07 21:05:39 CEST; 1s ago
    Trigger: Fri 2023-04-07 21:10:00 CEST; 4min 19s left
   Triggers: ● dummy.service

● dummy.service - dummy one-shot service for timer testing
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dummy.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-04-07 21:05:39 CEST; 1s ago
TriggeredBy: ● dummy.timer
    Process: 1805980 ExecStart=echo Dummy start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1805980 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms
```

However, the timer doesn't fire and gets stuck in a "running" state:

```
# systemctl status dummy.timer dummy.service 
● dummy.timer - Trigger dummy service every 5'
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dummy.timer; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-04-07 21:05:39 CEST; 35min ago
    Trigger: n/a
   Triggers: ● dummy.service

● dummy.service - dummy one-shot service for timer testing
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dummy.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-04-07 21:05:39 CEST; 35min ago
TriggeredBy: ● dummy.timer
    Process: 1805980 ExecStart=echo Dummy start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1805980 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 1ms

Apr 07 21:05:39 myvps echo[1805980]: Dummy start

# systemctl list-timers dummy
NEXT LEFT LAST                         PASSED    UNIT        ACTIVATES
n/a  n/a  Fri 2023-04-07 21:10:09 CEST 30min ago dummy.timer dummy.service
```

It looks like the timer doesn't understand "active (exited)" as terminated. Am I trying something impossible? Otherwise there something fishy.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like the timer doesn't understand "active (exited)" as terminated.

Because the unit is *active*. Whether the process has terminated is irrelevant to timers; what matters is whether the unit as a whole is still in the "active" state, which means it cannot be activated again – at least not without stopping it first.

Of course, the unit remains in "active" state because you have `RemainAfterExit=yes`.

If you want the timer to periodically re-apply changes, you will need to remove that option and split the service into two regular oneshot services, one to apply the state and another to un-apply it.